# What database can store trees?

Tags: database, performance, tree, linked-list, store

Is there a DB out there that can store tree structures (like for nested comments) without using anti-patterns or such.
I think LDAP is one, but are there any others?

I need to be able to index childes as well. I need it to be easy to move a branch from one node to a different node and be fast to read + format.

I have seen other similar questions. The problem with those (for me) they ask what is the most efficient way to do it in db XXX, while I ask which DB I should use.

Comment: Don't most document databases cater for this? Alternatively, look at graph databases

Comment: @Oded - Today I researched MongoDB, it appears it does not http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547886/can-a-mongodb-collection-have-inside-it-another-collection I would assume others to be the same, if you know one that does, please post its name.

Comment: Look at RavenDB and Neo4J. I am not sure what "without using anti-patterns or such" means - it is very abstract.

Comment: Rather than just NoSql you'd be looking for Graph Databases

Comment: You almost certainly want to store the data itself as XML.  Then the question becomes "what's the best way to store, retrieve and manipulate the XML"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relational databases won't be the best for this if the tree is very deep.  I'd recommend a graph or object database.

"Storing comments"?  Like those following blogs or articles?  If that's the case, I'd say that you can assume they won't be that deep.  A ten level comment tree would be exceptional.

In that case, a simple relational parent/child relationship using foreign keys would be sufficient:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS article
(
    article_id integer not null auto_increment,
    comment_id integer,
    primary key(article_id),
    constraint fk_comment foreign key(comment_id) references article(article_id) on delete cascade on update cascade
);
```

Comment: :-D check it http://www.tapuz.co.il/Forums2008/ViewMsg.aspx?ForumId=308&MessageId=157872690   Wish it was restricted "just" to 10 This is just one main post out of many...

Comment: Do you know that a relational database can't work?  Try it until it doesn't, then switch to something like a graph database.  XML is hierarchical, too.

Comment: Have you added indexes?  Profiled the code?  EXPLAIN PLAN?  Do you know the root cause of "slow"?

Comment: Got data to support that?  Have you profiled the app?  Looked at memory?  I'll be surprised if you say "yes".

Comment: well, not memory, but I had "hard-coded" the trees of a single page with about 200 posts, and the difference is noticeable. By hard coding I mean, I generated the trees, and then caching only that output (apc).

Comment: Still subjective - do you know that the time is spent in querying, or something else in your code?  You don't know - that's my point.

Comment: I would say relative and not subjective, but I see your point. One thing Intuitively for me though, It seems such development will be faster and easier to maintain on a linked list DB (Graph DB, I believe).

Answer (score 0):

"Relational Databases", of course, emphasize "tables" (2-D relationships).

Among RDBMS vendors, there are many different alternatives.  For example, DB2 has "hierarchical structures", and Oracle has "hierarchical queries":

- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0506melnyk/
- http://www.orafaq.com/node/2038

More generally, most of the major RDBMS products (MS Sql Server, IBM DB2, Oracle) have all become XML-aware.  This provides a more robust, portable approach to manipulating structured data.

Of course, among non-RDBMS vendors, there are even more alternatives for dealing with non-relational data (like trees).  Correspondingly, there's less portability - locking yourself into one "non-SQL database" more often than not locks you OUT of easily migrating your application to a different database.

BOTTOM LINE:

If you *can* use XML with a relational database, that's probably your best option.  Here are some good links:

- http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/links/#hierarchical
- http://www.techrepublic.com/article/shred-xml-data-with-xquery-in-sql-server-2005/6140404
- http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14259/xdb_xquery.htm
- http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg247298.html

'Hope that helps!

Comment: Relational tables hold sets of n-dimensional points (SQL tables hold bags) & represent n-ary relation(ship)s/associations. (A "relation(ship)" in the sense of FK or FK constraint as misused by pseudo-relational & pesudo-ERM presentations does have an associated 2-D relationship on subtuples of the FK & referenced  subrows.) (Ironically the most basic form of tree can be characterized as a binary relation on nodes.)